# How to make 4K wallpaper scretch over 4x 1080p monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization, 4k-resolution

I've got a 4 monitor setup, each one is 1080p and i can't seem to get a 4K picture to scretch over all the monitors instead the wallpaper is shrunk and applied to each screen; which altohugh is fine it's not what i'm going for.

Is there a way i can get the wallpaper to stretch over the 4 screens?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tool like [Display Fusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/Features/Wallpaper/).